# Uploading a file to a custom path in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload a file but I keep getting a "The upload path does not appear to be valid." error. The problem is the path I'm trying to upload to is in the directory just outside the current one. The current folder structure is as follows:

```
application
assets
 - uploads
  - profile_pictures
Admin
 - application
 - assets
```

I am attempting to upload a picture from the admin application into the 'assets/uploads/profile_pictures' folder which is in the main application root directory. The only issue is correcting the path.

**Here's the code from the Controller:**

```
public function update_image(){

  $user_id= $this->input->post('user_id');
  //$user_id=$this->input->post('user_id');
  $query5 = $this->db->get_where('user_details', array('user_id' => $user_id));
  $name_user = $query5->row()->name;
  $name='profile_image_edit';

    $user_img=$this->function->upload_profile_images(array($name), $name_user);
    var_dump($user_img);

    $this->db->set("image_path",$user_img);
    $this->db->where("user_id",$user_id);
    $update = $this->db->update("users");
    if($update)
    {
      echo 'Profile Image Updated.';
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'Profile Image Update Failed.';
    }
}
```

**And here's the code from the Model:**

```
public function upload_profile_images($names, $username)
{
       $config['upload_path']='./assets/uploads/profile_pictures';
       $config['allowed_types']='jpeg|jpg|png';
             $path = $_FILES[$names[0]]['name'];
       var_dump($names[0]);
       var_dump($path);
       $ste_d =date('YmdHis') . gettimeofday()['usec'];
                    $newName = str_replace("",'',str_replace("",'',"$ste_d.str_replace(" ",'_',str_replace(".","",pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME)))."_muddy.")).pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                  $config['file_name'] = $username ."_". $newName;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->load->library('upload', $config['upload_path']);

     $check = true;
     for($i = 0; $i < count($names) && $check; $i++)
     {
       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($names[$i]))
            {
                 $path='./assets/uploads/profile_pictures';
          $this->load->helper("file");
          $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
          var_dump($error);
          // delete_files($path, true);
          $check = false;
                 return false;
       }
            else
            {
          $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
          $check = true;

          return 'assets/uploads/profile_pictures'.'/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
       }
     }
 }
```

How do I set a custom path so the file is always saved in the desired directory of assets/uploads/profile_pictures from the Admin application. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'd have to check the code in `$this->upload->do_upload()`. My guess is it's preventing you from changing the base directory. There's already a lot of modifying the filename going on this code. It's unclear what the precise side effects are.

Comment: Are you trying to upload the file from `Model`? If yes try doing it from the `Controller` and insert the data from `Model`

Comment: I gave that a try too and it did not work.. getting the  same upload path is not valid error